# Video player in Flutter with own methods to play, pause etc

Tags: flutter, video

I need to add the video player to my Flutter app. Is there a way to display video but use my own methods to play, pause and stop presenting the video?
Now I'm using video_player dart package and when I'm calling my methods it doesn't work, the video reacts only on methods called on controller from package.

I need something to display the video only(widget?) and be able to manage it by myself. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Hi You need to use chewie its based on The video_player plugin and provides low-level access to video playback.
here:- https://pub.dev/packages/chewie

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll have a look at it

Answer (score 1):

You can use [_ControlsOverlay](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player/example) or `create your custom controller widget using stack` for any video player.